# Using {{outlet}} as variable name in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following Ember template;

```
{{#with model}}
<h2>Order #{{id}}</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Outlet</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{outlet}}</td>
            <td>{{date}}</td>
            <td>{{#link-to 'next-route' this}}Go{{/link-to}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{{/with}}
<hr>
{{outlet}}
```

How to do I keep Ember from using the first `{{outlet}}` (which is just the property's name) to add the next view I'm transitioning to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outlet` is a reserved word, that being said, if you fully qualify it it will work.

In your case, with the `with` block you can't fully qualify it, but if you remove the with block it will work.

Personally I'd avoid using it, it's analogous to having a variable named `for` or `if`

```
<h2>Order #{{id}}</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Outlet</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{model.outlet}}</td>
            <td>{{date}}</td>
            <td>{{#link-to 'next-route' this}}Go{{/link-to}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
{{outlet}}
```

Comment: To keep the `model.` bit from repeating, I was using `#with`. But I guess it's one thing or the other.